# Whenever does not trigger Sidekiq job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, sidekiq, whenever

I am trying to setup a Sidekiq scheduler to run recurring jobs.

I can get the Sidekiq job to run fine in Rails console, or Rails app. I can get Whenever to trigger command. However, I CANNOT get Whenever to trigger Sidekiq job.

I replicated my work in different machines, and in some machine, I get it to work. In most other machine, it is not working.

Here is my setup:

```
# app/workers/create_random_product.rb
class CreateRandomProduct
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    new_product = Product.new
    new_product.name = "Product #{Time.now}"
    new_product.price = 5.5
    new_product.save
  end
end

# config/schedule.rb
every 1.minute do
  runner "CreateRandomProduct.perform_async"
  command "echo 'hello' >> /home/vagrant/output.txt"
end
```

As you can see in the schedule.rb, I can get the second command to run because I can see the output updated, but the first runner command does not seem to do anything. Sidekiq dashboard does not show any activity either.

Running "whenever" returns these cron jobs:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/vagrant/sidekiqdemo && bin/rails runner -e production '\''CreateRandomProduct.perform_async'\'''

* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'echo '\''hello'\'' >> /home/vagrant/output.txt'
```

I ran the first command manually and it DOES trigger the Sidekiq job.

I did run the "whenever -i" command to update the crontab file. I check the crontab log, and I can see that it tried to trigger the Sidekiq job:

```
Oct 16 16:15:01 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 CRON[13062]: (vagrant) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/vagrant/sidekiqdemo && bin/rails runner -e production '\''CreateRandomProduct.perform_async'\''')
Oct 16 16:15:01 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 CRON[13063]: (vagrant) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'echo '\''hello'\'' >> /home/vagrant/output.txt')
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: any solution to this problem?

Comment: I haven't found one. I ended up using Sidetiq gem instead. It is not a perfect solution, but what it does is to have a job reschedule itself.

Comment: thanks @Khanetor, I actually did the same thing. will try to debug it and get back here

Comment: I just run successfully your code, one thing to get it working was update crontab by cleaning it: `crontab -r` and then `whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'` to test on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this defining a new `job_type` as suggested [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/scheduling.rb#L39).
To let this work you have to install [sidekiq-client-cli](https://github.com/didil/sidekiq-client-cli) as well.

Moreover I discovered thanks to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work) post that when a command is executed from the cron process only a set of the environment variables are set so in my case I the command was not working because my `BUNDLE_PATH` wasn't set. at the end my working `job_type` is something like this:

```
job_type :sidekiq, "cd :path && BUNDLE_PATH=/bundle /usr/local/bin/bundle exec sidekiq-client :task :output"

every 1.minute do
  sidekiq "push GenerateExportsWorker"
end
```

this is the reason why in my case a command like

```
every 1.minute do
  command "echo 'you can use raw cron syntax too' >> /home/log/myscript.log 2>&1 "
end
```

despite the other.

Comment: Do you know any reason why runner does not work?